# Golang SSH session ANSI Escape Codes

Tags: go, user-interface, ssh

I'm creating an scp-tui but I can't get terminal colors to work, I need them because I have to differenciate folders from files. When I call the command `ls` it returns only the string with the list of the files without colors. How can I get it working?

```
    session, err := sshClient.NewSession()
    handleError(err)
    defer session.Close()

    // Set up terminal modes
    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.ECHO:          0, // disable echoing
        ssh.ECHOCTL:       0,
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
    }

    err = session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes)

    handleError(err)

    var output []byte
    output, err = session.Output("ls")

    fmt.Printf("output: %v\n", output)
    return string(output), err
```

P.S. Are there better ways to get a list of files and folders of the current directory?

Update: I temporarely resolved the issue by executing two distinct commands to get first the files and then the directories.

Comment: "Are there better ways to get a list of files and folders of the current directory?" Use an SFTP session instead of plain SSH. SFTP has commands to get listings of remote directories. You can also use it to transfer files, instead of SCP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The fact is that I want to be able to do everything with SSH alone without the need of other services installed on the server.

Comment: `ls` tailors its output to its standard output, and (by default) only colorizes its output when writing to a terminal. You'll need to provide the correct option (varies by implemenation) to `ls` to tell it to colorize its output no matter what its standard output is.

Comment: I tried to run `ls` with some options like `--color` or `--color=always` but it doesn't change anything. Do you know how I could do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how the terminal output color is implicitly rendered based on the code provided. That said I found this piece and hope it helps out. https://twin.sh/articles/35/how-to-add-colors-to-your-console-terminal-output-in-go.

Comment: It's always better to add relevant content from the link as links aren't permanent.